# How can I get my prompt back after starting Emacs from the command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, emacs, cmd.exe

After I type `emacs somefile` at the command prompt and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I don't get my prompt back until after Emacs closes.

How can I run Emacs so that I get the prompt back immediately after Emacs starts?

On *nix systems, I can type `emacs somefile &` to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

#### How can I run Emacs so that I get the prompt back immediately after Emacs starts?

Use the following command:

```
cmd /k emacs somefile
```

If somefile contains spaces in the filename then use:

```
cmd /k emacs "some file"
```

---

#### Start a new CMD shell and (optionally) run a command/executable program.

> **Syntax**
>
> `CMD [charset] [options]`
>
> `CMD [charset] [options] [/C Command]`
>
> `CMD [charset] [options] [/K Command]`
>
> Options
>
> `/C`     Run Command and then terminate
>
> `/K`     Run Command and then return to the CMD prompt.
>             This is useful for testing, to examine variables
>
> `Command` : The command, program or batch script to be run.
>                This can even be several commands separated with '&' 
>                (the whole should also be surrounded by "quotes")

Source [cmd](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [cmd](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) - Start a new CMD shell and (optionally) run a command/executable program.

Comment: That won't work as expected, as you'd still reuse your current shell window. To just run emacs you could also just use the start menu or the run dialog, without the detour through calling `cmd`.

Comment: @Mario "I don't get my prompt back until after Emacs closes." - the above does **exactly** what the OP asked for (How can I run Emacs so that I get the prompt back immediately after Emacs starts?). Using the start menu or run doesn't answer his question.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you then. If you open a console window using `cmd` and then run `cmd` with whatever parameters, you'll get one instance running inside the other, but you won't return back to your command prompt unless emacs closed. If you'd put your command line into the run dialog, you could just ommit `cmd /k` and run `emacs` instead. At least that's my thinking regarding that solution.

Comment: @Mario The `/k` switch causes the "child" cmd to immediately terminate (without waiting for "Command" to finish - just like the unix `&`). That leaves us with the "parent" cmd and emacs still running. Try it and see ;)

Comment: Okay, then emacs behaves differently to what I expected, since I thought it won't return to the calling instance of `cmd` (which therefore wouldn't exit in time).

Answer (score 1):

By default the launched process will reuse your current console window. You can avoid that simply by using `start` to launch the separate process, i.e. rather than running `emacs myfile` you'd run `start emacs myfile`, which will open a new console window for the process. You'll then immediately return to the command prompt, just like you do on Unix systems.

As an alternative, you could install a version of bash for Windows (e.g. through MSys) and use the syntax you're used to.